# C# linking group policy in AD

Tags: c#, .net, active-directory

How do I set group policies in AD?  I'm able to create my OU but i also need to attach group policy linking to it.  So this is what i have so far.

```
 string strOU = "OU=test454545,OU=Clients,OU=Clients,DC=domain,DC=net";
        GPMGMTLib.GPM gpm = new GPMGMTLib.GPM();
        GPMGMTLib.GPMConstants gpc = gpm.GetConstants();
        GPMGMTLib.GPMDomain gpd = gpm.GetDomain(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("USERDNSDOMAIN"), "", gpc.UseAnyDC);  
        GPMGMTLib.GPMSOM gpSom = gpd.GetSOM(strOU);

        GPMGMTLib.GPMGPO gpo = gpd.CreateGPO();
        gpo.DisplayName  = "TestOutCome";
        gpSom.CreateGPOLink(-1,gpo);
```

This still doesn't create the GPO link, but all i want to do is link an existing GPO, anyt thoughts?  And thanks for the help.

Okay getting closer,  this just created a policy doesn't actually link an existing one...

```
 string strGPO = "Default Security with web access";
        string strOU = "OU=test454545,OU=Clients,OU=Clients,DC=domain,DC=net";
        GPMGMTLib.GPM gpm = new GPMGMTLib.GPM();
        GPMGMTLib.GPMConstants gpc = gpm.GetConstants();
        GPMGMTLib.GPMDomain gpd = gpm.GetDomain(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("USERDNSDOMAIN"), "", gpc.UseAnyDC);
        GPMGMTLib.GPMSearchCriteria searchOBJ = gpm.CreateSearchCriteria();
        searchOBJ.Add(gpc.SearchPropertyGPODisplayName, gpc.SearchOpEquals, strGPO);
        GPMGMTLib.GPMGPOCollection objGPOlist = gpd.SearchGPOs(searchOBJ);
        GPMGMTLib.GPMSOM gpSom = gpd.GetSOM(strOU);
        GPMGMTLib.GPMGPO gpo = gpd.CreateGPO();
        gpSom.CreateGPOLink(-1,gpo);
```

Update and WORKING:

This is for linking existing GPO's to OU's using C#
1) install http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/confirmation.aspx?FamilyID=0a6d4c24-8cbd-4b35-9272-dd3cbfc81887
2) Reference gpmgmt.dll (found in the install directory)
3) You might have to install .Net 1.1
4) Add References to VS
5) add using GPMGMTLib; using GPOADMINLib; to project

```
            string strGPO = "Default Security with web access";
        string strOU = "OU=test454545,OU=Clients,OU=clients,DC=domainh,DC=net";
        GPMGMTLib.GPM gpm = new GPMGMTLib.GPM();
        GPMGMTLib.GPMConstants gpc = gpm.GetConstants();
        GPMGMTLib.GPMDomain gpd = gpm.GetDomain(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("USERDNSDOMAIN"), "", gpc.UseAnyDC);
        GPMGMTLib.GPMSearchCriteria searchOBJ = gpm.CreateSearchCriteria();
        searchOBJ.Add(gpc.SearchPropertyGPODisplayName, gpc.SearchOpEquals, strGPO);
        GPMGMTLib.GPMGPOCollection objGPOlist = gpd.SearchGPOs(searchOBJ);
        GPMGMTLib.GPMSOM gpSom = gpd.GetSOM(strOU);
        GPMGMTLib.GPMGPO gpo = gpd.CreateGPO();
        gpSom.CreateGPOLink(-1,objGPOlist[1]);
```

Comment: anybody?  this cant be impossible...

Comment: You asked 22 minutes ago.  Be patient.

Comment: so gpd.GETSOM("Default Security with web access") is creating a NEW ou?

Comment: no it was creating a new blank GPO

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take a look at this [link](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyId=38C1A89B-A6D2-4F2A-A944-9236999AEE65&displaylang=en)

It contains a lot of sample scripts, you will need to add a reference (COM) to GPO Admin 1.0 Type Library from GPOAdmin.dll.

There is a similar issue discussed [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/csharpgeneral/thread/f3f5a61f-2ab9-459e-a1ee-c187465198e0) with a sample script in C#

**EDIT**:

Reference gpmgmt.dll as COM interop and use the code as below:

```
Public Function CreateAndLinkGPO(ByVal strDomain As String, ByVal strOU As String, ByVal strGPOName As String)
    Dim gpm As New GPM()
    Dim gpmConst As GPMConstants = gpm.GetConstants()
    Dim domain As GPMDomain = gpm.GetDomain(strDomain, "", gpmConst.UseAnyDC)
    Dim som As GPMSOM = domain.GetSOM(strOU)

    'create new GPO
    Dim gpo As GPMGPO = domain.CreateGPO()
    gpo.DisplayName = strGPOName 

    'create link to OU
    som.CreateGPOLink(-1, gpo)

    CreateAndLinkGPO = gpo
End Function
```

This is in VB.NET, but can be easily ported to C# posted by a [MSFT poster from here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vbgeneral/thread/fcbd4eae-96c7-4a5f-8e5a-cf5b8a2542c7/). I think the key is .[CreateGPOLink](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa373492%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), [GPMSOM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa814192%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is your OU (Retrieves the IGPMSOM interface that represents the domain or the organizational unit (OU) at the specified path.)

Comment: I saw that, but how do you actually link it to the OU?

Comment: I'm able to find that GPO using that example, but is there any example of CopyTo to a specific GPO?

Comment: okay figured it out, giving you the answer i added the whole solution above because it took me like a day to work it out.

Answer (score 2):

I was looking for a way to simply list the GPOs that are linked to a particular OU, this thread helped me tremendously. I have the following sub to share. It doesn't list the names of the GPOs but returns the count. A minor mod will allow you to get the names (check out the properties of **GPOLink** in the foreach loop). You will need to have the GPMC installed and the gpmgmt.dll added as a project reference.

```
 private string getGPOLinkCount(string OUPathDN, bool onlyEnabledLinks, bool includeInheritedLinks)
    {
        int linkCount = 0;

        try
        {
            GPMGMTLib.GPM gpm = new GPMGMTLib.GPM();
            GPMGMTLib.IGPMConstants gpc = gpm.GetConstants();
            GPMGMTLib.IGPMDomain gpd = gpm.GetDomain(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("USERDNSDOMAIN"), "", gpc.UseAnyDC);

            GPMGMTLib.GPMSOM gpSom = gpd.GetSOM(OUPathDN);

            GPMGPOLinksCollection GPOLinks = gpSom.GetGPOLinks();
            GPMGPOLinksCollection GPOLinksIncludingInherited = gpSom.GetInheritedGPOLinks();


            if (!includeInheritedLinks)
            {
                foreach (GPMGPOLink GPOLink in GPOLinks)
                {
                    if (onlyEnabledLinks)
                    {
                        if (GPOLink.Enabled)
                        {
                            linkCount++;
                        }
                    }
                    if (!onlyEnabledLinks) //Get all links, disabled or enabled
                    {
                        linkCount++;
                    }
                }                   
            }

            if (includeInheritedLinks)
            {
                foreach (GPMGPOLink GPOLink in GPOLinksIncludingInherited)
                {
                    if (onlyEnabledLinks)
                    {
                        if (GPOLink.Enabled)
                        {
                            linkCount++;
                        }
                    }
                    if (!onlyEnabledLinks) //Get all links, disabled or enabled
                    {
                        linkCount++;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return "GPO links: " + ex.Message.Replace("\r\n", "");
        }

        return linkCount.ToString();            
    }
```