# GPO Link, Value does not fall within the expected range

Tags: c#, gpo, som

got a function that links a GPO to an OU:

```
using Microsoft.GroupPolicy;

private void LinkTheGPO()
{
    GPDomain domain = new GPDomain("city.dom");

    string sOU = "LDAP://city/ou=room,ou=house,DC=city,DC=dom";

    Som som = domain.GetSom(sOU); //ERROR AT THIS LINE

    som.LinkGpo(-1, gpo);
}
```

it throws this error :

```
Value does not fall within the expected range
```

my OU structure is :

```
City  
|  
|___House  
     |  
     |____Room
```

Comment: What is the `Type` of the exception?

Comment: @mjwills System.ArgumentException

Comment: Based on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5312157/c-sharp-linking-group-policy-in-ad I wonder if you have the format wrong. e.g. should `LDAP://city/` be there.

Comment: @mjwills when i remove LDAP://city/
it throws :
"There is no such object on the server. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80072030)" string

{System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException}